# Are activities on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

From the [FAQ](https://travel.stackexchange.com/faq):

> - customs & border crossing, visas and other travel documents such as permits
> - accommodation: camping, hostels & backpackers, guesthouses, B&B's, hotels, renting a villa on a trip
> - loyalty programmes: frequent flyer points and hotel advantages
> - health and safety issues related to travel
> - modes of travelling: international, domestic, and public transport
> - finances: budgets, costs, foreign exchange
> - working while on the go (WWOOFing, volunteer travel etc) - not immigration or work visas, see below

What about *activities to do while travelling*?
When travelling, people could do many activities, some that are particularly touristic, but some that aren't.
The FAQ currently doesn't mention activities as on-topic at all.
For a particular activity, how do we determine if it's on-topic or not?

- Going on a tour boat on a canal?
- Visiting a museum?
- Going to the zoo?
- Visiting a shopping centre?
- Hiking up a mountain?
- Going to a pub, restaurant, night-club?
- Recommendation for book store, library?

Many of those questions I may very well ask of the place where I live.  However, they also relate to what people may do while travelling.  How do we draw the line?  Should the FAQ mention activities at all?

Answer (score 5):

We have plenty of questions like this, and generally if it's part of travel - activities that people like to do when going - eg hiking Kilimanjaro when they go to Africa, then yeah it's on topic.

All of the examples you give are probably on topic, EXCEPT the recommendation one - recommendations/polling are considered off topic.

Comment: I don't think recommendations conflict with our topic, they conflict with our rule against subjectivity. Thus even on-topic recommendation questions are possible, but not suitable for the site. This doesn't explain why we actually have quite a few recommendation questions though.

Comment: Agree in general that just the word recommendation isn't off topic, but asking for recommendations on a book shop for example, is polling :/

Comment: If they're all on-topic it should be mentioned as such in the FAQ, because from the FAQ I would judge it as off-topic.